# Change js confirm() to look like bootstrap3 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need know that I cannot change the look of confirm() but is there any easy way to have use bootstrap3 modal same way as confirm()? Right now I have in my HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(user.userId)" del-confirm="Do you really wish to delete: {{user.login}}" >Delete</button>
```

and my directive look like:

```
app.directive('delConfirm', [function() {
    return {
        priority: -1,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                var message = attrs.ngConfirmClick;
                if (message && !confirm(message)) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And it works fine. When I click delete directive either stops propagation or lets ng-click call function. But I cannot recreate that using modals. Also had no luck using angular-dialog-service since it returns promises and don't know how to make it to stop propagation in right time. 
Calling function inside Yes answer is not really good solution for me since I will need use it in few diffrent pages each with diffrent controller and in some of them I have few diffrent functions that I want to confirm before calling. Current solution works great because I have just one directive that works everywhere because HTML is calling appropriate function inside ng-click, which is suspended until confirmation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *can't* optionally stop propagation of an event based on asking the user something except with `confirm`, because `confirm` brings the JavaScript engine to a screeching halt until the user does something. Instead, you have to *always* stop propagation and, in the callback for whatever modern mechanism you're using (which will be asynchronous with your event processing), initiate the event that the propagation would have triggered.

Comment: Thanks, that might work probably but newbie question here. How can I initiate the evant again? If I have it like this I'm just calling back click and getting new modal window:

http://pastebin.com/hBVXW1H4

Comment: You don't. You just call your code to do whatever it was you wanted to do. I mean, you *can* raise events synthetically, and sometimes it's useful, but in the normal case you probably wouldn't for something like this.

Comment: Well as I mentioned in question I need to confirm few different clicks like: 

<button class="btn btn-danger" has-permission="users.delete"  ng-click="removeSelected()" del-confirm="Do you really wish to delete: {{selectedUsersLogins}}" >Remove selected</button>

 <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(user.userId)" del-confirm="Do you really wish to delete: {{user.login}}" >Delete</button>

wouldnt it make me create diffrent directives for each function?